# How to persist selected radio button value, and the dropdown to database?

Tags: database, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is my form :

```
    <form  method="POST" th:action="@{/registration}" class="form-horizontal" th:object="${user}" role="form">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" class="form-control  input-lg" placeholder="" />
    <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" class="form-control  input-lg" placeholder="" />
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Gender</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio"                                        id="femaleRadio" value="F" />Female
                                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio"                                id="maleRadio" value="M" />Male
                                </label>

    <input type="date" id="birthDate" class="form-control  input-lg" />
    <input type="text" name="email" value=""class="form-control  input-lg" placeholder="" />
    <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" value="" class="form-control  input-lg" placeholder="" />
    <select class="form-control  input-lg">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Please select an option </option>
                <option value="one"> 1</option>
                <option value="two"> 2</option>
                <option value="three">3</option>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="submit">
            </form>
```

And this is my controller that saves this into the database

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createNewUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    User userExists = userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());
    userService.saveUser(user);
    modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "User has been registered successfully");
    modelAndView.addObject("user", new User());
    modelAndView.setViewName("registration");
    }
    return modelAndView;
}
```

And I use the userRepository.save(user)

The problem is, that are my fields get saved in the database except for the input type radio, the date and the select option. 
What is it that I need to change so that all fields get saved to the database ?
This is my user model:

```
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
@Column(name="gender")
private char gender;
@Column(name="birthday")
private Date birthDate;
@Column(name="selectedOption")
private String selectedOption;
```

The date in the model is imported from java.util.Date;
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know much about the technology you're using, but what if you changed the radio inputs to a select dropdown instead?

Comment: Thank you,but it is required to be a radio button.

Comment: normally a radio button has a `name` attribute. This may be different for what you're doing but I notice a `th:field` attribute on your other fields. Maybe try `th:field="gender"` or `name="gender"` on your radio inputs? (I'm still just guessing...)